# Tornado stuck on switching protocol pending

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-2.7, websocket, tornado

I'm trying to get websockets to work with tornado. Using Wireshark I see the data being sent to my PC. But Chrome Dev just shows it as switching protocols "pending"

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you provide your code?